# Is this a thread-safe module, and actually how do you write one?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm actually working with a multi threaded program which involves lots of mysql operations, and basically it's quite a pain as you have to come up with a smart way to make all queries work. This got me thinking that how you can make a module thread safe.

Anyway I'm trying to ask my question in this way: say you need to constantly append new content to a txt file with lots of different threads, `main.py` would definitely work as below:

```
import threading

lock = threading.RLock()

def AppendStr(the_str):
    write_thread = threading.Thread(target = RealAppending, args = (the_str, ))
    write_thread.start()

def RealAppending(the_str):
    lock.acquire()

    the_file = open("test.txt", "a")
    the_file.append(the_str)
    the_file.close()

    lock.release()

def WorkerThread(some_arg):
    do stuff

    AppendStr("whatever you like")

for counter in range(100):
    new_thread = threading.Thread(target = WorkerThread, args = (some_arg, ))
    new_thread.start()
```

Well, the thing is, if I'm trying to make the codes neat and easier to maintain, **does it still work if I put the codes below into** `write.py`:

```
import threading

lock = threading.RLock()

def AppendStr(the_str):
    write_thread = threading.Thread(target = RealAppending, args = (the_str, ))
    write_thread.start()

def RealAppending(the_str):
    lock.acquire()

    the_file = open("test.txt", "a")
    the_file.append(the_str)
    the_file.close()

    lock.release()
```

**and do it like this in** `main.py`: (I don't truly understand how `import` works in python)

```
import write

def WorkerThread(some_arg):
    do stuff

    write.AppendStr("whatever you like")

for counter in range(100):
    new_thread = threading.Thread(target = WorkerThread, args = (some_arg, ))
    new_thread.start()
```

And also what if there are lots of other modules using `write.py` in a multi-threaded way, and then you import those modules in `main.py` and call different `def` from there. Would everything work out as expected? If not, what should I do to design a ultimate thread-safe module which can be used like this?

**If you `write.py` is imported in lots of other modules, do they all share the same `lock`? What's the scope of variables in such modules?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this looks like a threadsave module but there are mistakes:

this is a better version:

```
def RealAppending(the_str):
    lock.acquire()
    try:
        the_file = open("test.txt", "a")
        try:
            the_file.write(the_str) # write
        finally:
            the_file.close()
    finally: # if an error occurs
        lock.release()
```

because:

- if an error occurs when writing to the file the lock must be released

the syntax above is for python 2.3 and lower

here is the improved version that does exactly the same:

```
def RealAppending(the_str):
    with lock:
        with open("test.txt", "a") as the_file:
            the_file.write(the_str) # write
```

So yes, your module is threadsave.
There is some stuff that can be added to prevent users from using it in an nonthreadsave manner:

```
# write.py
__all__ = ['AppendStr'] # put all functions in except the ones others shall not see
# so id you do from write import * nothing else will be imported but what is __all__
```

But still you cannot know in which order the strings will be written to the file.

Comment: Or just use the with context for the lock

Comment: Well if you import this module from lots of different other modules, do they all share the same `lock`? If so I guess it would be thread-safe, but I'm just not sure how `import` works and what scope of `lock` is

Comment: if you import a function into another module it still keeps the old global variables it is defined in. No problem if lock is also in another module: RealAppending.func_globals is write.__dict__